# $f$ cont., $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact, invariant $\Rightarrow$ ($f$ transitive $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$ dense orbit)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

In [Martelli's book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471319759.html) "Introduction to Discrete Dynamical Systems and Chaos", (p.208), the following theorem is stated without proof:

> "**Theorem 6.2.1** *Assume that for every $x\in X$ and every $r>0$, there exists $n\geq 1$ such that $F^n(B(x,r)\cap X)=X$. Then there exists $x_0\in X$ such that $L(x_0)=X$*."
>
> > (Where $L(x_0)$ is the set of limit points of the orbit of $x_0$ under $f$, i.e. $\{f^n(x_0)\}_{n\geq 0}$. Also $L(x_0)=X$ is used as definition of a **dense in $X$** orbit.)

*Even if not explicitly stated in the theorem, it is (to me at least) also clear from the context, that we may additionally assume that $F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, $X\subset U$ is closed, bounded and invariant. I think it is also clear that $F^n(B(x,r)\cap X)=X$ implies that $f$ is [topologically transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics)#Topological_mixing) in $X$.*

In a paper by Stephen Silverman [[Silv](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1181072815)], from 1992, the existance of a dense orbit is denoted as **DO**, and topological transitivity of $f$ as **TT**.

It is explained at [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_transitivity), that **DO** and **TT** are not equivalent in general, but it is proved in [[Silv](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1181072815)] (Prop. 1.1) that $X$ [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set), [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space) and [second category](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondCategory.html) ensures that **TT** implies **DO**. This would then apply to a compact set $X$ as above.

**Question**: I am now trying to come up with a proof (essentially of **TT** $\Rightarrow$ **DO**), under the assumptions above, that only includes fundamental analysis (say concepts from [[Rudin](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/principles-of-mathematical-analysis)]) or at least with as little prerequisites as possible (not first/second category, etc.). Say, using that $X$ is closed bounded. It feels like it should be simple enough, and perhaps it is obvious and I have misunderstood one or more of the concepts, but I would love some help.

*Thoughts: What we want to show is that, given $x\in X$ arbitrary, we can find a $x_0\in X$ such that every neighborhood $N_\epsilon (x)$ of x, contains points of $\{f^n(x_0)\}_{n\geq 0}$. By covering $X$ with a finite cover of balls $\{B_i\}$ of radius $\frac{1}{k}$, and finding $x_k$ whose orbit visits each $U_i$ for such a cover, then finding a sequence $\{x_k\}$ that converges to some point $x_0$ could do. It is obvious that for each such $x$, there is some point $p$ in an open neighborhood of a point $x_0$ that will eventually get mapped into a neighborhood of $x$, but I cannot see how we can find one $x_0$ that works for all neighborhoods of $x$.*

*(The level here is approx. undergraduate in mathematics.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and $F : X \to X$ a map with the property that for any $x \in X, r > 0$ there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $F(B(x, r)) = X$ (here $B(x,r) = \{ y \in X : d_X(x, y) \leq r\}$, so we need not intersect with $X$; it is most convenient to work with closed balls).

Fix a dense sequence $\{ x_i\}_{i = 1}^\infty$. Define $r_n = 1/n$. I'll define iteratively a sequence of nonempty closed sets $U_1\supset U_2 \supset \cdots$ as follows. First, $U_1 := B(x_1, r_1)$. Next, let $n_1$ be such that $F^{n_1}(B(x_1, r_1)) = X$. Define
$$
U_2 := U_1 \cap F^{-n_1} B(x_2, r_2) \, ,
$$
noting that $U_2 \subset U_1$ is nonempty and closed, and $F^{n_1} U_2 = B(x_2, r_2)$.

Inductively, given $U_1 \supset \cdots \supset U_m$ closed and $n_1, \cdots, n_{m-1}$ for which $F^{n_1 + \cdots + n_{m-1}} U_m = B(x_m, r_m)$, define $n_m$ so that $F^{n_m} B(x_m, r_m) = X$ and set $U_{m+1} = U_m \cap F^{-(n_1 + \cdots + n_m)} B(x_{m+1}, r_{m+1})$.

By the finite intersection property, $\cap_{m \geq 1} U_m$ is nonempty and so contains a point $x_0$. To check density observe that $d_X(F^{n_1 + \cdots + n_{m-1}} x_0, x_m) \leq r_m = 1/m$. So, if $x = \lim_{i \to \infty} x_{m_i}$ for a subsequence $\{ m_i\}$, then
$$
x = \lim_{i \to \infty} F^{n_1 + \cdots + n_{m_i - 1}} x_0 \, .
$$

Comment: Please excuse the inactivity (due to illness) on my part. I am now trying to understand your proof. I do have a bit of a hard time following everything. First of all, I assume that $F^{-n}(x)$ means $F^{-1}(F^{-1}(...F^{-1}(x))...)$ right? So it is the inverse image of $F^n$? Sorry if I have misunderstood something trivial but, how do I see that $U_2$ is nonempty and that $F^{n_1}(U_2)=B(x_2,r_2)$?

Comment: I am starting to think that this is somewhat similar to my initial idea. I have tried to tweak my proof, in which I start out with a cover. I am really tired now but the gen. idea is: $\{B^{r_i}\}_k \supset X$ is a cover of balls of radius $r_i$, $U_1\subset X$. Let $n_1$ be s.t. $F^{n_1}(U_1)=X$. Then for each $B^{r_1}_k, \exists u_{1_k}\subset U_1$ s.t. $F^{n_1}(u_{1_k})\cap B^{r_1}_k\not = \emptyset$. Let $U_2=\cup_k u_{1_k}\subset U_1$. Then do the same for a cover $B^{r_2}_k$, and so on for each $r$ in a seq. $\{r_k\}\to 0$. I get a sequence $U_1\supset U_2...\supset U_k$ but I am..

Comment: (also let $n_2$ be s.t. $F^{n_2}(U_2)=X$, then for each $B^{r_2}_k \exists u_{2_k}\subset U_2$ s.t. $F^{n_2}(u_{2_k})\cap B^{r_2}_k\not = \emptyset$ (... and so on.) I get a sequence, like you, ..., $U_1\supset U_2\supset ... \supset U_k$, but I am not sure how to see that there is one point $x_0$ whose orbit will visit every set in every cover $\{B^{r_i}\}_k$ for $r_i \to 0$, which I guess is part of your last §. I must sleep now, but I will ponder some more on how to adjust my original idea to work and/or fully understand your proof before I accept. I hope this is ok, and thank you.